# What problems can occur if I delete Elasticsearch index directories by hand rather than using the delete API?

Tags: elasticsearch

My Elasticsearch cluster has run out of memory.  There are some indices that can be deleted, but Sense queries produce no response, so I manually deleted one of these indices, and then tried to shut down and restart all the nodes in the cluster.  That's not working, I'm getting all kinds of errors.  Is it dangerous to manually delete directories under /nodes/0/indices in order to get rid of indices?

Comment: What are those errors?